# what is wrong in this

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE  FUNCTION `work_exp`(id int(11)) RETURNS varchar(255)
BEGIN
DECLARE sid varchar(255)
SELECT group_concat(company_name) INTO sid FROM work_exp where studentid=id 
IF(sid>0) THEN
RETURN (sid)
ELSE
RETURN ('0')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reason why the statement failed:

- you haven't change the delimiter
- you haven't ended the statements with `;`
- you haven't close the `IF` statement with `END`

query:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE  FUNCTION `work_exp`(id int) 
RETURNS varchar(255)
BEGIN

    SET @sid := (SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT company_name)
                 FROM work_exp 
                  where studentid=id); 

    IF (CHAR_LENGTH(@sid) <= 0 OR @sid IS NULL) THEN
       SET @sid := 0;
    END IF;

    RETURN @sid;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: this also give an error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Answer (score 0):

Close The 'If' statement before return